# How does Dual Pixel Raw work

Tags: canon, raw

My Canon EOS R has a feature called Dual Pixel Raw.
From my understanding, each pixel on the sensor is split in two and the stored as two parallel Raw files in one "physical" file. Specialized software like Canon Digital Photo Professional can then pull extra detail out of the Dual Pixel Raw file.

But what about a "regular" Raw file from the EOS R? Does it contain the combined value for each of the dual pixels?

Or is there a Main and a Secondary Pixel in the Dual pixel pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "Main" and "Secondary" photosites (a/k/a sensels or pixel wells) on a dual pixel sensor. There are only "left" and "right" photosites for each location. When a raw file is saved without preserving the discrete information from each one, the two values are combined in a single value recorded in the raw file.